# How to get the io_context from a strand in Boost 1.68?

Tags: boost-asio

I have a `boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>` object and need to get its `io_context`. I thought that I could use `get_io_context()` but that has been deprecated. Then I thought that I could use `context()` but that one returns a `boost::asio::execution_context`.
I cannot see how I can convert this into an instance of `io_context` instead...

So, how can I get a strand's `io_context` in boost 1.68?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `get_inner_executor` on strand instance then `context` on executor:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand{io.get_executor()};

    boost::asio::io_context::executor_type executor = strand.get_inner_executor();
    boost::asio::io_context& refIO = executor.context();
}
```